# Getting record if any of the value matching on condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table info,

## __test

```
id  points   date
1    -50    30.09.2013
2    100    2.10.2013
3    100    3.10.2013
4    200    4.10.2013
```

From this i need to select records,if any of the value contains minus points based on the date

For ex:

```
select * 
from #__test 
where date between  30.09.2013 to  3.10.2013
```

Mentioned query is common for getting in between records fro two dates.But i need the records between two dates,if any of the value contains minus points.

How can i do this ? Kindly help me.

Comment: Presumably, your actual dates employ a DATE data type!?!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    #__test t
WHERE   t.Date BETWEEN '20130930' AND '20131003'
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    #__test t2
            WHERE   t2.Date BETWEEN '20130930' AND '20131003'
            AND     t2.points < 0
        );
```

It simply checks for the existance of a negative value in the date range and then returns **all** records for that date range if one is found.

*N.B [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is probably worth a read regarding using `BETWEEN` for date ranges, and there is further reading on date range queries in [another article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) written by [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand)*